# Web app with client-side encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption, ssl

I am developing a web application which will encrypt data on the client side, then send the data to a server. The server will store the encrypted data, but will *not* have the ability to decrypt  the data. The point is to keep the client's data secure, so that not even the server hosts have access to the data. This can be guaranteed by the fact that the server only receives encrypted data and never receives the key.

I plan to use Javascript for the encryption and decryption on the client side. Additionally, the connection will be secured with SSL.

I read the article here: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/ which suggests that Javascript should not be used for encryption, but it doesn't address my use case.

Is this a secure solution? Is there a way that I can make it more secure?

Comment: This seems secure enough as long as you don't actually inject JS code to steal the key.

Comment: And nothing else on that page is from anything other than your server.  And the user is not running any extensions in their browser that allow the extension access to webpages they visit (which is plenty).  Actually your situation is covered by that article - as it goes on to say how the RNG is not secure in a browser, so theoretically, there's nothing you can do.   Like most security issues, you'll never be able to say "it's secure".  You can just express a level of confidence.

Comment: @Nik: Wouldn't such browser extensions be able to steal data from *any* web app, regardless of encryption happening on the client-side or not? I don't have a good feeling about encrypting client-side with Javascript, but I don't know whether third-party scripts or extensions are the reason.

Comment: Yes  - since extensions often have very access to the DOM, it's kind of game over. So many of the most useful extensions require this, for every url. They're not the entire reason not to trust client side encryption, just another thing to be considered when trying to work out whether a browser solution could be described as "secure".

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at the [Host-Proof Hosting](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Host-Proof_Hosting) pattern (from July 2005).

> **In A Blink Sketch:**
>
> Locked inside data cloud, key at browser.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Host sensitive data in encrypted form, so that clients can only access
>   and manipulate it by providing a pass-phrase which is never
>   transmitted to the server. The server is limited to persisting and
>   retrieving whatever encrypted data the browser sends it, and never
>   actually accesses the sensitive data in its plain form. It. All
>   encryption and decryption takes place inside the browser itself.

Key points are you need to still use TLS/SSL and have full trust in the host serving both the HTML as JavaScript resources.

Also, [Web-browser encryption of personal health information](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1472-6947/11/70) has a solution similar to what you are looking for.

[image: Encryption data flow]

Answer (score 0):

Although there isn't anything inherently wrong with this setup, since it's the clients responsibility to maintain the security of their own machine, I think you may be getting into a situation that might cause more issues.

One being that users expect to be able to get access to their data no matter what.  If they're on another system that has JS turned off, then they won't be able to access their data.

Another, what happens if a user forgets their password/key?  Since you're not storing it, you can't recover the data and it's effectively lost.  There won't be anything you can do and even though it's not your fault, the users won't see it that way.

Just some food for thought.